# Malplotlib Histograms is not working properly

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)
final_tails = []
for x in range(100) :
    tails = [0]
    for x in range(10) :
        coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
        tails.append(tails[x] + coin) 
    final_tails.append(tails[-1]) 
plt.hist(final_tails, bins = 10)
plt.show()
```

some bars are missing, anyone know how to solve this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkmFt.png)

tried searching for it but haven't found a solution yet

Comment: You have 10 bins, but you only get the values 1-8 in `final_tails` it seems.

Comment: i just changed plt.hist(final_tails, bins = 10) to plt.hist(final_tails, bins = range(10)) and it works but i have no idea why

Comment: From the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html): _"If bins is an integer, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the range.

If bins is a sequence, it defines the bin edges, including the left edge of the first bin and the right edge of the last bin; in this case, bins may be unequally spaced."_

Comment: I'm sorry, i know python for a week now, i don't have any idea the meaning of that. Can you explain in a beginner doo-doo way?

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the bins that are created by `plt.hist`, which we can do by inspecting the return value. According to [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) the second return value is the bin edges. Additionally, let's look at the range of values present in final_tails:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)
final_tails = []
for x in range(100) :
    tails = [0]
    for x in range(10) :
        coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
        tails.append(tails[x] + coin) 
    final_tails.append(tails[-1]) 
bin_counts,bin_edges,patches = plt.hist(final_tails, bins = 10)
print("Min value is {}, max value is {}".format(min(final_tails), max(final_tails)))
print("Bin Edges are : " +str(bin_edges))
print("Bin Counts are : " +str(bin_counts))
plt.show()
```

which prints

```
Min value is 2, max value is 9
Bin Edges are : [2.  2.7 3.4 4.1 4.8 5.5 6.2 6.9 7.6 8.3 9. ]
Bin Counts are : [ 2. 10. 23.  0. 21. 27.  0. 10.  6.  1.]
```

**Why are some of your bars "missing"?** `final_tails` only contains whole numbers and if we look at your bins, then `4.1 4.8` and `6.2 6.9` are two bins that do not cover a whole number. The values `4,5,6,7` from `final_tails` will fall into the bins `3.4 4.1`, `4.8 5.5`, `5.5 6.2` and `6.9 7.6` respectively.

**Why did we get such "weird" bin edges?** Per the docs again:

> If bins is an integer, it defines the number of equal-width bins in the range

You specified a number of bins (10) and what pyplot does is look at the min and max value in your array and then set 10 equally sized bins. Since you are only in the range 2-9 (see min and max value), the bins end up having a width <1. to fix this, you can specify the bins manually. You know that you want bins from 0-10, so you can do:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)
final_tails = []
for x in range(100) :
    tails = [0]
    for x in range(10) :
        coin = np.random.randint(0,2)
        tails.append(tails[x] + coin) 
    final_tails.append(tails[-1]) 
bin_counts,bin_edges,patches = plt.hist(final_tails, bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) #or bins=range(11)
print("Min value is {}, max value is {}".format(min(final_tails), max(final_tails)))
print("Bin Edges are : " +str(bin_edges))
print("Bin Counts are : " +str(bin_counts))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, the bars aren't missing, the values are going up its just the bin width size that you have that's making the graph spaced out (you should only have 8). try changing the graph bin width dynamically like this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)
final_tails = []

for _ in range(100):
    tails = [0]
    for _ in range(10):
        coin = np.random.randint(0, 2)
        tails.append(tails[-1] + coin)
    final_tails.append(tails[-1])

# Specify a fixed bin width to avoid gaps
bin_width = 1
num_bins = int((max(final_tails) - min(final_tails)) / bin_width)

plt.hist(final_tails, bins=num_bins, range=(min(final_tails), max(final_tails)), edgecolor='black')
# Adding edgecolor for visibilty 
# you don't need the range here but its good practice
plt.show()
```

hope this helps